# jQuery Mutltiple delegation on container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a buttons which should be handlad by ajax and they should be delegated on its container:

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', 'a', function() {
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass('myButton1') {
      //handle
     return false;
   } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('myButton2') {
      //handle
      return false;
   }
})
```

so I thought about improving this:

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', 'a.sharedClass', function() {
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass('myButton1') {
      //handle
     return false;
   } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('myButton2') {
      //handle
      return false;
   }
})
```

what do you think, will it improve my code IF:

1. I have many buttons: its a news stream and every news node have its own buttons like delete, favorite, spam, open media lightbox, vote, view votes and etc..
2. there are other anchors which are not handled by ajax.

Comment: question is probably more suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Would really need to provide more details for anyone to evaluate

Comment: Check out the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question and how I usually approach this is by using the HTML5 `data` attribute. I'd use a data attribute like so `data-actionFn = 'delete'`.

**HTML**

```
The two below trigger ajax calls onclick

<a href="#" data-actionFn='delete' class='js-ajax'> delete </a>
<a href="#" data-actionFn='vote' class='js-ajax'> vote </a>
....

This does not trigger an ajax call

<a href="#"> do something </a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', 'a.js-ajax', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var actionFn = $(this).data('actionFn'); // grab function name

    if (window[actionFn]) {
        window[actionFn]();
    } else {
        // throw Error here
    }
});

function detele(){
    // put code here
}
function favorite(){
    // put code here
}
function spam(){
    // put code here
}
function open(){
    // put code here
}
function media(){
    // put code here
}
function lightbox(){
    // put code here
}
function vote(){
    // put code here
}
function view(){
    // put code here
}
```

**NB:**
This is just to give you an idea of how you could implement it.

Comment: and this is definatly interesting approach! I'll remember this, but sandly this does not answer my question. first it does not satisfy second argument 'there are other anchors which are not handled by ajax', which is a permalink to news. of course I can make an exceptions, or just check for data. but the qiestopm is different and tries to find best approach on delegation, to do not fill memory with anchors that are not used by making a shared class.
 but indeed I'm going to use this also

Comment: if the anchors are not triggering ajax requests then just delegate click event to the shared class of the anchor tags that use ajax. I'll update it ;)

Comment: now this is exactly what I was talking about :) in your opinion will it be better that first version I wrote? I just needed second opinion )

Comment: Your improved version plus my idea should work well. :)

Comment: small note: data attributes are automatically lowercased (at least in my chrome) so `$(this).data('actionFn');` will not work in this case. just had to lowercase them all